# How do I transfer images from public database to Google Cloud Bucket without downloading locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, md5

I have a a csv file that has over 10,000 urls pointing to images on the internet. I want to perform some machine learning task on them. I am using Google Cloud Platform infrastructure for this task. My first task is to transfer all this images from the urls to a GCP bucket, so that I can access them later via docker containers.

I do not want to download them locally first and then upload them as that is just too much work, instead just transfer them directly to bucket. I have looked at [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview) and for my specific case I think, I will be using a [URL list](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list). Can anyone help me figure out how do I proceed next. Is this even a possible option?
If yes, how do I generate an MD5 has that is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list#md5) for each url in my list and also get the number of bytes for image for each url ?

Comment: If you have to provide a size and hash of each file, and you don't already have each of those files available locally to examine, you're going to have to download them to get that data anyway.  If you download the file, then you might as well just upload it immediately, while you have it around.

Comment: So is there no other way to "transfer" it to bucket directly without using any hash or byte information?

Comment: I don't know, but the service you're looking at seems to require it.  The use case is for developers who fully manage all the content they want to upload, then automate that upload, probably from other servers they control.  It doesn't sound appropriate for scraping random URLs to store.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. Let's say hypothetically, I download the file, how do I generate an MD5 hash corresponding to each url for each image that is downloaded.The documentation just mentions md5-test as an example [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list#md5) which is not clear

Comment: There are lots of resources out there to find out how to MD5 some file content in your chosen language. It's a very common task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, Storage Transfer Service requires that you provide it with the MD5 of each file. Fortunately, many HTTP servers may provide you with the MD5 of an object without requiring that you download it. Issuing an HTTP `HEAD` request may result in the server providing you with a `Content-MD5` header in its response, which may not be in the form that Storage Transfer service requires, but it can be converted into that form.

The downside here is that web servers are not necessarily going to provide you with that information. There's no way of knowing without checking.

Another option worth considering is to set up one or more GCE instances and run a script from there to download the objects to your GCE instance and from there upload them into GCS. This still involves downloading them "locally," but locally no longer means a place off of Google Cloud, which should speed things up substantially. You can also divide up the work by splitting your CSV file into, say, 10 files with 1000 objects each in them, and setting up 10 GCE instances to do the work.